# Why is cp -ax /media/hdd /media/ssd creating a hhd folder in media/ssd instead of copying files there?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clone

I am using liveCD to clone the file system from one drive (hdd) to an ssd (I am trying to migrate my system to use SSD)

I mounted `/dev/sdb1` (my former hdd) to `/media/hdd`
I mounted `/dev/sda1` (my ssd) to `/media/ssd`
I am using the command

```
sudo cp -ax /media/hdd/ /media/ssd/
```

when I do a dir `/media/ssd` I see a folder called hdd !??? Why is this happening?

**Update:**
Now I will edit the `/etc/fstab` on the ssd to point to the new fs UUID ( I will look it up with blkid ).
Here is the output of the command:

```
cp -ax /media/hdd/* /media/hdd/.* /media/ssd/
```

The errors that you see there are the reason why I am migrating to SSD. This PC is always up and the HDD seems to have problems.

Now ..should I worry about the hard links not being created ?

Now I will edit the `/etc/fstab` on the ssd to point to the new fs UUID ( I will look it up with blkid ).

My next move is to update grub on ssd using the following:

```
sudo -s
for f in sys dev proc ; do mount --bind /$f /media/ssd/$f ; done
chroot /media/ssd
grub-install /dev/ssd
update-grub
```

Considering the above and the errors shown in the picture should I expect any problems?

Edit2: I restored GRUB using the procedure described here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  very easy for a beginner. The above command lines did not work for me

[image]

Comment: As for edit 2, the hard links can be copied over with the `rsync` way in @A.B.'s answer. The IO errors mean the files there are essentially gone for good. Luckily, though, they're all Linux headers. That means that, once you get everything else copied over and you boot from the SSD, you can use `sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-generic` then `sudo apt-get autoremove` then `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` to reinstall the headers.

Comment: I am using the computer without those links. What is their purpose and how come that the computer is working fine?

Comment: Looking more closely at the hard link error messages, it's saying it's not going to create a hard link from a file to that same file, so never mind on the hard links. The headers can be repaired with `apt-get`, though.

Comment: great that means that I am fine. I will fix the headers if I ever need to use them (I guess some app compiled from sources might ask for them down the road) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy something to a file, it overwrites the file if it exists.

When you copy something to a directory, it could be rather dangerous to destroy everything that might currently be in the directory to replace it with new contents, so it copies **into** the directory.

That's why `hdd` is being copied into the `ssd` directory.

If you instead do `sudo cp -ax /media/hdd/* /media/hdd/.* /media/ssd`, it will copy all the files within `hdd` into `ssd`.

The `*` means all the unhidden files inside `hdd`. The `.*` means all the hidden files inside `hdd`.

Comment: You don't need the `p` or the `R` as they are already included in `-a`.

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer because it was the first posted. A.B. s anser is also good and more complete Thanks guys.

Comment: @user2059078 Than give me at least an upvote :\

Answer (score 1):

### The `cp` way

The command:

```
sudo cp -ax /media/hdd/ /media/ssd/
```

copies the folder `hdd`, the command:

```
sudo cp -ax /media/hdd/* /media/ssd/
```

copies the files and sub-folders of the folder `hdd`.

Use:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

for considering dot files.

---

### The `rsync` way

```
rsync -az -H --delete --numeric-ids /media/hdd/ /media/ssd/
```